# How to handle DNS with AWS when you have no spare elastic ips available?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

The problem: I've currently got over 5 different ec2 instances that use elastic ips for DNS purposes - this is so that when I restart the server I don't lose my IP address (that is refrenced to in route 53). I created a new ec2 instance only to discover that I have exhausted the elastic ip limit (5).

I would happily use the public DNS host name that is assigned to each ec2 instance, but it turns out that this changes everytimw the server reboots - and I don't want to have to wait for DNS changes to propagate every time I need to reboot the server.

Perhaps I'm missing something incredibly obvious, but is there any unique identifier that I can use in route 53 (similar to the way you would approach an s3 bucket) or another nice way that doesn't involve needing to change DNS records every time I reboot the server?

Thanks!

Comment: > By default, all AWS accounts are limited to 5 EIPs, because public (IPv4) Internet addresses are a scarce public resource. We strongly encourage you to use an Elastic IP address primarily for the ability to remap the address to another instance in the case of instance failure, and to use DNS hostnames for all other inter-node communication. If you feel your architecture warrants additional Elastic IP addresses, please complete the Amazon EC2 Elastic IP Address Request Form. We will ask you to describe your use case so that we can understand your need for additional addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MichaelHampton - I ended up going the route of asking for more elastic ips and was successful. For my own learning though, public DNS hostnames appear to change every time I restart the server - which makes them unsuitable as a cname in route 53. I guess the point of my question was without using elastic ips is there some unique identifier (similar to s3) that you can use for DNS purposes or would you need to use some dynamic DNS solution?

Comment: @Joel, Have you considered Route53 ALIAS records? (not to be confused with A records).  ALIAS records allow you to point a record set to a target such as an ELB which you could register your EC2 instances against.  This prevents you from having to worry about the IPs changing and could mean you don't even need EIPs.  This can also be set up in a private subnet if required.